# telerik multiselect not triggering events

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik, multi-select

I have this multiselect in a asp.net mvc project:

```
<div class="demo-section user-selection">
        <h3 class="title">1. Select one or more Users</h3>
        @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()    //user multi select
  .Name("customers")
  .DataTextField("givenName")

      .DataValueField("description")
      .Events(events => events.Change("Selection"))
      .DataSource(source =>
        {
            source.Custom()
                .ServerFiltering(true)
                .ServerPaging(true)
                .PageSize(5)

                .Type("aspnetmvc-ajax") //Set this type if you want to use DataSourceRequest and ToDataSourceResult instances
                .Transport(transport =>
                {
                    transport.Read("Virtualization_Read", "Home");
                })
                .Schema(schema =>
                {
                    schema.Data("Data")
                          .Total("Total");
                });
        })
      .Height(400)
      .Virtual(v => v.ItemHeight(55).ValueMapper("valueMapper"))
      .HeaderTemplate("<div class=\"dropdown-header dropdown_Users\">" +
                              "<span class=\"k-widget k-header\">Photo</span>" +
                              "<span class=\"k-widget k-header\">Contact info</span>" +
                          "</div>")
                                                        .ItemTemplate("<span class=\"k-state-default item-user userPic\"><img class=\"userPhoto\" src=\"" + @System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseUrl"] + "user/image?userIid=#:data.IID#\" /></span>" +
                                                                  "<span class=\"k-state-default item-user \"><h3>#: data.givenName # #: data.sn #</h3><p>#: data.description #</p></span>")
        )
    </div>
```

then i have a function called Selection

```
    function Selection() {
                console.log("sel");

                ...

            }
```

My problem, is that when i select users for the multiselect, the function doesnt get called. i dont see "sel" in console. if i change the event to DataBound it triggers, but the change event doesn't
Whats wrong?

Comment: code seems fine.  i'd try `alert("sel");` instead of console.log, or just add your function into the change property like `events.Change(@<text>function() { alert("sel"); }<text>)`

Comment: i actually just tried to change the event from Change to Select and it started working :)

Comment: both events should fire though according to their "events" demo http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/multiselect/events